# how to see the query generated by spring ldapTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap

I am using spring ldapTemplate version 1.3.2 to query results from active directory. We would like to be able to see the query generated by ldapTemplate.search() and similar methods in order to debug deployments of our product to clients.

So far we have tried looking in the docs to see if there's a "toString" method that would provide this but didn't find anything. We also changed the debug level in log4j.properties file:`log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`. This seems to give us more verbose output but doesn't actually display the full ldap query string.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If anybody has any info it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is still an open ticket on the spring side:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/345

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this information is currently not logged by the library. It does seem reasonable that it should be able to do so though. Please file a jira issue here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/LDAP, and please make sure to be as specific as possible with regards to what should be logged.

Finally, I would like to encourage you to upgrade to the latest version of the library. Current version is 2.0.2.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. Is it possible for us to implement this and submit a patch? I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using an `LdapQuery` object for an `LdapTemplate` or `LdapRepository` search method, you can log the `Filter` returned by `LdapQuery.filter()`.

Example:

```java
LdapQuery query = query().where("someAttribute").is("some value")
    .and(query().where("objectClass").not().is("unwanted"));
log.debug("LDAP query: " + query.filter());
List<?> results = ldapTemplate.search(query, myAttributesMapper);
```

... will log ...

```
LDAP query: (&(someAttribute=some value)(!(objectClass=unwanted)))
```